# Proving/disproving differentiability on a cube root

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the following question: I need to prove or disprove that $f$ is differentiable at $x_{0}=1$ when I have the function $f(x):\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$, defined by $f(x)= \sqrt[3]{x^3-x^4},\quad \forall x\in \mathbb R$.
I have tried to approach this in a million different ways and have not made any progress. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think you have to try different ways, it's sufficient to find the derivative and look what happen at $f'(1)$

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I would suggest you get an "image" of the function so that you have an idea of whether you want to prove or disprove it. (SPOILER ALERT: it's not differentiable at $x_0 = 1$).

My I Idea would be to look at the differential quotient, from left:
$$\lim_{h \downarrow 0} \frac{f(x) - f(x - h)}{h}$$

Which, after some refactoring and setting $x=1$ leads to the following:
$$ \lim_{h \downarrow 0} - \frac{1}{h} \sqrt[3]{h}(1-h) $$

And now you check how the quantity $ - \frac{1}{h} \sqrt[3]{h}(1-h) $ behaves for small $h > 0$. For that, consider first the three terms $ \frac{1}{h}, \sqrt[3]{h}, (1-h)$ separately.
There you could see, one tends to $-\infty$, the other to $0$, and the last one to $1$. The limit is only valid, it is not infinite, therefore the question is, is $\sqrt[3]{h}$ going fast enough to $0$, s.t. the product $\frac{1}{h} \sqrt[3]{h}$ is well defined, i.e. finite?

And here you see, or maybe you have to prove*, that the product will tend to $\infty$ and therefore the limit is not defined and the function is not differentiable in $x_0 = 1$.

*The product is a quotient of two polynomials, with orders $1, 1/3$.